# Move item in array to another array

Tags: ruby

Let's suppose that we have arrays `x = ['a', 'b', 'c']` and `y`. Is there an easy way to move, say, the second element of `x`, to `y`? So that in the end, `x` is `['a', 'c']` and `y` is `['b']`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yep, it would look like this:

```
y.push x.delete_at(1)
```

`delete_at` will delete an element with given index from an array it's called on and return that object

Answer (score 9):

A special code for this example. It might not work on your other arrays. Instead of actually moving element, let's take the old array apart and construct two new arrays.

```
x = ['a', 'b', 'c']

x, y = x.partition {|i| i != 'b'}

x # => ["a", "c"]
y # => ["b"]
```

The `delete_at` approach is likely better for your situation, but, you know, it's good to know alternatives :)

Answer (score 4):

Yes. For a specific element:

```
y = []
y << x.delete('b')
```

For a specific index:

```
y = []
y << x.delete_at(1)
```

This kind of stuff is [well documented](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html), btw.

Answer (score 2):

```
x = ['a', 'b', 'c']
y = []
```

To delete by index:

```
y << x.delete_at(1)
```

To delete by object:

```
y << x.delete('b')
```